# Primefaces Accordion and TabView issue after open

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, user-interface, primefaces

I have problem with Primefaces Accordion and TabView. When i put TabView with 2 and more Tabs into Accordion panel and open my page first time, all tabs was display at once. Then when i change tab by click other header it's all back to work correctly.

My structure is:

```
<p:accordionPanel>
  <p:tab>
   <p:tabView>
     <p:tab id="tab1">
       Content 1 here
     </p:tab>
     <p:tab id="tab2">
       Content 2 here etc.
     </p:tab>
   </p:tabView>
  </p:tab>
<p:accordionPanel>
```

I try to using activeIndex="0", but it won't help.

Comment: Your code won't work in first line because title is mandatory for tabs. Second, how should anyone know what version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Primefaces version: 3.5

After added title it's won't work anyway.

Comment: Check if you're having some javascript error when your page gets loaded, that could cause some extrange behaviour with PF components. Also try to do it like [PF Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/accordionPanel.jsf) shows, that should definitely work.

Comment: Works for me (with `title` set on all `<p:tabs/>`). Add more context to your question. Something else is broken in your view. Also check your javascript console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `activeIndex` property of the JSF Accordion like this:

```
<p:accordion id="accordionView" activeIndex="#{myBean.tabIndex}">
```

And put in your backing bean a `@PostConstructor` to search

```
  public static final String INDEX_PARAM = "index_get_param";

  @Inject
  private transient HttpServletRequest httpReq = null;
  private int tabIndex = 0;
  @PostConstruct
  public void init()
  {

    if (httpReq != null)
    {
      String indexParam = httpReq.getParameter(INDEX_PARAM);
      if (indexParam != null)
      {
        searchTypeParameter = searchTypeParameter.toUpperCase();
        if (indexParam.equals("FIRST")
          tabIndex = 0;
        if (indexParam.equals("SECOND")
          tabIndex = 1;

      }
    }
  }

  public int getTabIndex()
  {
    return tabIndex;
  }
```

It works also with `p:tabView`